# Monitor Activity USB , D+ and D-

Tags: usb, hardware, monitor

I want to make a simple circuit to monitor if there is activity in a USB 'dongle'. Let's put an example, that I want to monitor if a 16GB usb dongle is working well (if it's not hung)

[image]

It's seems simple to monitor the D+ and D-, but the question is:

If the PC doesn't access to it, Does the USB protocol send packets to it, in order to 'control' it even if the PC is not reading/written it?

I want to detect if the USB 16GB dongle hangs or if the PC hangs too.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's easy, when you don't say which USB protocol is being used? USB 2 at 12 Mbps or 480 Mbps? USB3?

Comment: Yes, the PC constantly communicates with the USB device. So in order to detect real activity, you would need to partially decode the USB protocol. A 16GB drive most likely uses at least USB HS at 480 Mbps. So it's not trivial. You might find a creative solution, e.g. measuring the duration of USB communication and only assume real activity if it exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I'm not thinking to use USB3.0, only USB 2.0. Assuming that the speed is 480Mbps, it sound 'easy' to 'sniffer' both pins, D+ and D-, and when there are not changes for a certain period -> No activity. Is this statement correct? I don't want to 'decode' the USB protocol, I want to see if there is activity or not, so if I have aliasing effect at getting samples is not a problem.

Comment: No activity on USB bus means "SUSPEND". There is a relatively simple device that detects this state (and a bit more), you can get it here, https://www.kage-electronics.com/PRODUCTS.php

Comment: by the way, I cannot understand why someone rate me negative to ask a question...